# Extract a theme after a dot (in R)

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the theme (DPS3_2h) that is after the dot in:

`ABBCCAA.DPS3_2h`

Using a below command I am able to extract E15 that before the underscore. Not sure how to do it for the above example.

`E15_AAACCCAAGAGGCTGT`

`types <- sub('(.*)_.*', '\\1', colnames(E15))`

Comment: `sub('^.*\\.(.*)$', '\\1', 'ABBCCAA.DPS3_2h')` gives you `[1] "DPS3_2h"`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't bound to base R, the `stringr` package offers a lot of nice functions to work with strings. The pattern used here is using a positive look behind `(?<=)`.

```
stringr::str_extract("ABBCCAA.DPS3_2h", 
                     pattern = "(?<=\\.).*")
#> [1] "DPS3_2h"
```